# How to auto convert an & search query to %26

Tags: search, google-search

I've built a simple form that sends a user-created input query to `https://www.google.com/search?q=`

Everything works great, except for when the user enters an & in the search. So, for example, if the user input into the search form is  `Anderson, Johnson, & Smith Associates`, the query cuts off after `Anderson, Johnson` because Google doesn't recognize the `&`.

Is there a script or something I can add to the Submit button so that if the user query contains an &, that it automatically converts it to `%26`. So, for example, if the user entered `Anderson, Johnson, & Smith Associates` into the form, the corresponding query that is sent to Google is:  `https://www.google.com/search?q=Anderson,%20Johnson,%20%26%20Smith%20Associates`

Comment: In what language are you constructing the URL in? JavaScript? C#? Python? Each language has its own utility function but what you’re looking for is basically to escape HTML entities within the string. For JS there is `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()`, for example.

Comment: Simple javascript. 

Basically, the button has this attribute:  var custom_query = button.getAttribute("data-query") 

Followed by the var associated with each input field. 

With a:

 f ( tname_value.length > 0 ){ 
     query_string += 

That pulls the associated VAR that corresponds to the input field. 

The scripts ends with a    query_string += custom_query;

   window.open(query_string);

 }

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to parse the string before adding it to the URL, i.e.:

```
var url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(<YourStringHere>);
```

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var query = document.querySelector('#query').value;
  var url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

  console.log(url);
  const link = document.querySelector('#link');
  link.href = url;
  link.innerHTML = url;
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="query" value="Anderson, Johnson, & Smith Associates" />
<button type="button" id="button">Search on Google</button>

<a href="#" id="link"  target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, Terry. Unfortunately, because I'm adding Boolean logic automatically to the query, that doesn't work. In your example, the <YourStringHere> query is going to be different on every search. So, for example, search one might be "acme corporation." Search two might be "Anderson, Johnson, & Smith Associates." So the query itself needs to stand alone. SO, ANOTHER WAY TO PHRASE THE QUESTION: somewhere in the script, I need to have an IF/THEN element. Meaning IF <YourStringHere> contains an &, THEN convert & to %26.  Is that possible?

Comment: @sandyscott I don’t understand your comment. What does Boolean logic have anything to do with this? You’re simply encoding/escaping illegal characters so that they aren’t parsed as a query string reserved character. `encodeURIComponent` does the encoding itself and you don’t need to check if it contains an `&` or not to replace the character.